# Class not registered. Looking for object with CLSID:

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsx, vs-extensibility

I had created a custom project system with the help of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc512961.aspx. And which is working fine that I can create a project with the extension of.Myproj in the VS Experimental Instance window. But when I go to the properties in the created project, (Solution Explorer: Right click on the project folder and select properties) it will show an exception that "Class not registered. Looking for object with CLSID: {00000-00-00-000000}" How can I provide a Properties window for this projection system or can I modify the Properties window for any other default VS project system? Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried enabling "break when exception thrown"? What's the call stack at that point?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your own property page for your project package, e.g.:

```
...
[ProvideObject(typeof(YourPropertyPage))]
public class YourPackage : ProjectPackage
{
    ...
```

Where `YourPropertyPage` is a type derived from [`SettingsPage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.settingspage(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp):

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa")]
public class YourPropertyPage : SettingsPage
{
    ...
```

More Info about creating project property page on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc826178.aspx#sectionToggle8).

Comment: Thank you Yuriy. But the link you mentioned walk through is guiding to create property pages for solution properties. (Solution Explorer-> Right Click on Solution and select Properties) I don't want to modify solution properties, I need to customize project properties (Solution Explorer-> Right Click on Project and select Properties) by adding new tabs and other items for my custom project system. Hope you understand the difference. Please guide me through my need.

Comment: @MathivananKP, the second link I provided - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc826178.aspx#sectionToggle8) - describes how to create the property page for a **Project**, not the Solution - exactly what you're looking for. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Yuiry. Please see the difference. Create a project and In Solution Explorer click Solution node->Right click->Properties (a small dialog which appears in the center of the screen) and click Project folder node->Right click->Properties. (a wide screen which appear in the entire code editor pane)